# calculate order difference between 2 arrays (global and local)

Tags: algorithms

**Actual Problem**: I want to assess the difference in two text rewrites: `it can be fine today => today, it can be fine`
**Simplified Problem:** `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] => [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. (Note: it could actually become `[6, 2, 3, 4]` for example)
**Goal**:
Find some difference score that assesses the global new order, and the local new order.

**Does anyone know any order difference algorithms for this?**

My Ideas:

Global: I can compare compare numeric difference of new word locations.

Local: Not quite sure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the difference between two arrays, but to the original problem, assessing the differences between two texts, you should use BLEU score. See example:

```
import re
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu

def format_arr (text):
  filtered_text = re.sub(r'[.,:";]', '', text)

  return filtered_text.split(' ')

reference = [format_arr('I believe today will be a wonderful day')]
candidate = format_arr('today, I believe it will be a wonderful day')
score = sentence_bleu(reference, candidate)
print(score)
```

Scores under 0.2 could be considered very different, scores over 0.45 could be considered not very different.